# Using XPath 1.0, how can I have more than one anonymous function operating on the extracted content?

Tags: regex, r, xml-parsing, concatenation

With R, `httr` and `XML` you can scrape this site; the relevant HTML code is below.

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.mehaffyweber.com/Firm/Offices/", useInternal = TRUE)

<div id="content">
<img id="printLogo" style="padding-bottom:30px" src="/images/logo_print.jpg">
<div id="contentTitle">
<div style="height: 30px;">
<h1>Offices</h1>
<h3>Beaumont Location:</h3>
<p>
<p>
<br>
<h3>
<strong>Houston Location:</strong>
</h3>
<p>
<p>
<h3>
<strong>Austin Location:</strong>
</h3>
```

To extract only the cities where this company has offices, this XLPath 1.0 code works:

```
(string <- xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", function(x) {
  gsub("Location:|\\W|Â", "", xmlValue(x, trim = TRUE))}))
```

I tried to paste the state to the city with a second anonymous function but failed:

```
> (string <- xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", function(x) {
+   gsub("Location:|\\W|Â", "", xmlValue(x, trim = TRUE))} &&
+     function(x) {paste0(xmlValue(x), " , TX")}))
Error in { : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

So did a simpler try when I did not repeat `function(x)`

```
> (string <- xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", function(x) {
+   gsub("Location:|\\W|Â", "", xmlValue(x, trim = TRUE)) &&
+     paste0(xmlValue(x), " , TX")}))
Error in gsub("Location:|\\W|Â", "", xmlValue(x, trim = TRUE)) && paste0(xmlValue(x),  : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:** How might I combine both anonymous functions and create this string?

[1] "Beaumont, TX" "Houston, TX"  "Austin, TX"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. `htmlParse` is shorthand for `htmlTreeParse(..., useInternal = TRUE)`. 
You have issues with encoding on this document so the `RCurl` library will help to remove the strange encodings you are encountering.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
appHTML <- getURL("http://www.mehaffyweber.com/Firm/Offices/"
                  , .encoding = "UTF-8")
doc <- htmlParse(appHTML, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

`xpathSApply` is a shorthand for two operations. It applies the `xpath` to the `doc` and gets the relevant nodes. Then each of this nodes is applied to the function the user stipulates. The x passing to the function is basically the output from:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//h3")
```

or in shorthand

```
doc["//h3"]
```

Each element of `doc["//h3"]` is an internal XML node:

```
> str(doc['//h3'])
List of 3
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "XMLNodeSet"
```

So the `x` in your function is just like an element of `doc["//h3"]`. So you can experiment
with `doc["//h3"][[1]]`

```
x<- doc['//h3'][[1]]
temp <- gsub("\\WLocation:", "", xmlValue(x))
paste0(temp, ", TX")
[1] "Beaumont, TX"
```

Then you can apply this logic in your function:

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", function(x){
  temp <- gsub("\\WLocation:", "", xmlValue(x))
  paste0(temp, ", TX")
})

[1] "Beaumont, TX"         "Houston, TX"          "Austin, TX"
```

Comment: you also have to remove the Location: after Austin. That's what my two efforts with \\W and the odd A came in.

Comment: Very clear and useful explanation.  BTW, what would be a way to get XPath 2.0 implemented for R?

Comment: package `XML` uses `libxml2` which doesnt support `XPATH 2.0` http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/why-doesnt-libxml2-support-xpath-2-0 currently there seems to be no viable alternative to `libxml2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use `rvest` and `stringr` it's a pretty simple solution:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

pg <- html("http://www.mehaffyweber.com/Firm/Offices/")

found <- pg %>%
  html_nodes("#content") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_match_all("([[:alpha:]]+), Texas")  

sprintf("%s, TX", found[[1]][,2])

## [1] "Beaumont, TX" "Houston, TX"  "Austin, TX"
```

Comment: @hrbmstr: +1 for rvest.  BTW, your Scottish independence post was extraordinary!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get your desired result.

```
string <- xpathSApply(doc, '//h3', function(x) {
        paste0(sub('^([A-Z][a-z]+).*', '\\1', xmlValue(x)), ', TX')
})
# [1] "Beaumont, TX" "Houston, TX"  "Austin, TX"
```